# Django: I want to override exactly one module in a contributed library to patch one tiny thing

Tags: python, django, wsgi

There is *exactly one* module in the "pinax" contributed library – which is essential to my project – that I wish to override.  And that one module is `site-packages/pinax/templatetags/templatetags/shorttimesince_tag.py`, which references the `django.utils.tzinfo` module which no longer exists in current Django.  (Having been replaced by `django.utils.timezone`.

I would like to "override" this particular module by arranging things so that Python will encounter it first.  Well, I tried unsuccessfully to put this into the `wsgi` file of the application:

> `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "overrides")))`

I then created an `overrides/pinax/templatetags/templatetags` directory tree with an `__init__.py` file in each.

I don't think that Django gets this far, before it dies with an import error.  (Because a "print()" statement didn't produce any output.)

But, I feel that *something* along these lines ought to work.  Because I really don't want to have to absorb this entire contributed library into my application, literally just to change *one line of source.*

Any ideas?  Am I just barking up the wrong tree? *(P.S.: I am also using another library, the "machina" forum, which *does* include a very nice built-in "override" mechanism. But I don't know exactly how it works, and I haven't yet "dumpster-dived" to find out ...)

Answer (score 1):

Tested it with local files, and it seems, when you override a package by creating a package in `override` with same name and `__init__.py` inside, it overrides the whole original package, not just the files you've created. So you have to copy all the files from that package.

And if you don't specify `__init__.py`, python doesn't recognize your package and imports the original.

I think, the best way here is to fork the original package's repo, change it, and use the fork in your project. Also consider creating a PR to the original repo if you think your changes might be useful to others.

Comment: That seems to be the situation, yes.  I'll verify first check once more to see if the original package authors have actually abandoned it.  Thanks for the info.  The "individual override" mechanism created by the forum software that I selected was SO very nice ...